# Question regarding $\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(ax)\, dx$ and the improper integral of even functions

Tags: calculus

Consider the integral of the cosine function

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(ax)\, dx.$$

The property for an even function $f(x)$ is that $$\int_{-a}^{a} f(x)\,dx= 2\int_{0}^{a} f(x)\,dx.$$

However cosine doesn't have a limit at $\infty$ and $-\infty$.  Is it fair to say that it doesn't converge to a constant value?  People don't have problem saying that summing over sine equals zero because it's an odd function, even though it doesn't converge at infinity either:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(ax)\, dx = 0$$

Is it true that an even function $f(x)$ must have a limit at infinity for $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\,dx= 2\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)\,dx$$ to be true?

Comment: This limit does not converge

Comment: does that mean the integral doesn't have a value?

Comment: "...doesn't have a value".  Yes it does mean that. By definition, $\int_0^{\infty } ~f(x)dx = \lim_{b \to \infty} ~ \int_0^b ~f(x) dx.$  Consider the integral as the area under the curve.  If, as $b \to \infty$, $f(b)$ does not go to $0$, then the area under the curve **can not stabilize**.  Under this scenario, the integral **can't have a value.**

Comment: Who are all these people who have "no problem" saying that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(ax) dx$ has a value?

Comment: Re my previous comment, $f(b)$ going to $0$, as $b \to \infty$, although a *necessary* condition for a "convergent" integral, is **not** in general a **sufficient** condition.  The classic example is $\lim_{b\to\infty} \int_1^b ~(1/x) dx.$

Answer (score 3):

> People don't have problem saying that summing over sine equals zero because it's an odd function

No, they absolutely do have a problem saying that. There is a fact which may at first glance sound like that (see below), but it's quite different.

I think it's worth going back and thinking about the $\sin$ example. Contra your claim, the expression $$E:\quad\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(x)dx$$ is **undefined**. What *is* true is that for every real number $a$ we have $$\int_{-a}^a\sin(x)dx=0,$$ and so consequently $$\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-a}^a\sin(x)dx=0.$$ However, that's not enough to conclude that the expression $E$ above actually makes sense. You need to go back to the definition: we have $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx=k$ iff for all $\epsilon>0$ there are $a<b$ such that for all $a'<a$ and $b'>b$ we have $\vert k-\int_{a'}^{b'}f(x)dx\vert<\epsilon$. Note how the upper and lower bounds of the integral are not a priori related to each other; the fact that we always get $0$ when they match up is not enough to tell us that $E$ actually makes sense.

So there's no difference between $\sin$ and $\cos$ in this situation: for each of them, *none* of the various integrals involving $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ are actually well-defined.

Comment: @pico I upvoted and agree with Noah Schweber's answer.  However, I would have expressed it differently.  When considering $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} ~f(x)dx$, where $f(0)$ is well defined, then **regardless** of whether $f(x)$ is an odd (or even) function, you have to consider the two integrals $\lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{-a}^0 f(x) dx$ and $\lim_{b \to \infty} \int_0^b f(x) dx$ **separately**.  Each (improper) integral is expressed as a limit.  The only way for the *combination* of the two integrals to permit a specific value is if **each** of the two limits are **individually** convergent.

Answer (score 0):

Recall the definition of improper Riemann integrals:

> If $f$ is Rieman integrable in any interval $[0,b]$, then $f$ is (improperly) integrable in $[0,\infty)$ if
> $I=\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\int^b_0 f(x)\,dx$ exists and in such case, the $\int^\infty_0 f(x)\,dx:=I$

One way to convince yourself that $\int^\infty_0\cos (x)\,dx$ (drop $a$ for simplicity) diverges is as follows:

If the interval existed and had value $I$ (as an improper integral) then in particular we would have
$I=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int^{n\pi}_0\cos x\,dx$

Now,
$$
\begin{align}
\int^{n\pi}_0\cos x\,dx &=\sum^n_{k=1}\int^{k\pi}_{(k-1)\pi}\cos x\,dx\\
&=\sum^n_{k=1}(-1)^k=(-1)^n
\end{align}
$$

which does not converge.

---

For a function $f$ to be integrable (as an improper Riemann integral) over an infinite interval, it is not needed for $f$ have a limit as $x\rightarrow\infty$ or $-\infty$. Here is one example:

$f(x)=n$ if $n\leq x\leq n+\frac{1}{n^3}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and $0$ anywhere else.

In this case, one can check that
$\int^\infty_{-\infty}f(x)\,dx =\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^2}<\infty$.
Yet $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$ noes not exists.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is best to use the definition of a limit. We say that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists if $\exists L\in \Bbb{R}$ such that given any $\epsilon>0$, $\exists M\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon ~ \forall x>M$. It is easy to show that no periodic function can satisfy that definition. $\sin$ is the antiderivative of $\cos$, so we can conclude $\int_{\Bbb{R}}\cos(x)\mathrm{d}x$ doesn't exist since $\sin$ has no limit.